# Is there a NetBeans formatter for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, netbeans, text-formatting

My team uses NetBeans and has coalesced around NetBean's default formatting. Is there way to import NetBeans formatting rules for Java into Eclipse? There are a lot of Eclipse format plugins for NetBeans but none for the other way around, that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the [source code for the indenter](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/d1c37e25307b/editor.indent) gives me the impression that the formatter classes are tightly coupled to the editor and other netbeans-specific classes. Creating such a plugin would require bringing in these dependencies, along with the Netbeans platform to connect the pieces.

I wouldn't hold my breath for such a plugin to become available.

If you have the authority to challenge the team's decision, you could use this [maven plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.revelc.code/formatter-maven-plugin), tied to the lifecycle so that builds trigger a code reformat using eclipse's formatter. This way you lose one or two seconds when you build, but you don't have to explicitly reformat the files.

Comment: Here is the better link: https://github.com/revelc/formatter-maven-plugin